# Regex match all positive and negative number except 200

Tags: regex

How do I match all positive and negative numbers excluding 200.

I have tried the following and this regex works only for positive numbers but not for negative numbers.

```regex
^(?!(?:200)$)\d+
```

Expected result:

```
0
3
199
200 this is excluded
201 
-1  this should be a match
-10 this should be a match
```

0,3,199, and 201 match with the regex I tried

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it if the numbers appear at the beginning of the lines:

```regex
^(?!200\b)-?\d+\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dCuMkZ/1)

Explanation:
`^` Should be start from the beginning of the line.
`(?!200\b)` 200 should not come next.
`-?` minus is optional.
`\d+` the digit itself.
`\b` for word boundary. (The case @CarySwoveland mentioned in comment)

Comment: `\b` is better than `\s`. I would go for `(?!200$)` if it's to match a whole string

Comment: This matches `'221'` in `'221B'` (the latter being Sherlock Holmes' street number on Baker Street).